# Using LINQ grouping over List of records

Tags: c#, linq

I have defined following DTO object in C#:

```
public class Record
{
    public List<EventType> EventTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and after having List< Record> filled whereas EventType is defined as enum

```
public Enum EventType {
  UNLOCK = 1,
  LOCK = 2
}
```

Now I want to make a report similar to follow from List of Record:

```
count       Name
=====       ======
3           UNLOCK
1           LOCK
```

... by using (most likely LINQ group by). What would be preferrable approach to make this list? I assume that I will have to make yet another DTO that will hold that data.

Comment: what have you tried? Did you check this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the resulting data type you want to have, you can use either of these:

```
var result = records.SelectMany(x => x.EventTypes)
                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var result = records.SelectMany(x => x.EventTypes)
                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count());

var result = records.SelectMany(x => x.EventTypes)
                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Select(x => new YourType(x.Key, x.Count()));
```

The first will result in a dictionary with the event type being the key and the number of its occurrence in the list as the value.

The second will result in an enumerable of an anonymous type with the two property `Name` and `Count`.

The third will result in an enumerable of type `YourType` which gets passed the event type and the number of its occurrence into its constructor.

Comment: `record` should be replaced by `records.SelectMany(r=>r.EventTypes)`

Comment: Thank you, third item was what I exactly have tried to achieve :)